# Retrieve image from Database in winform

Tags: winforms

I want to retrieve data from database but i'm not able to retrieve image.I've taken TmagePath Datatype as nvarchar

[image]
PFB

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you must consider that the datatype in your Database of image must be VarBinary. Than try this:

```
var filename = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
byte[] getImg = new byte[0];
getImg = (byte[])filename["WImagepath"];
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(getImg);
Picwaiter.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Maybe usefull answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29589703/5603115